# How to check the disabled button is true/false ? in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi guys is there any ways on how to check the disable button ??

**Here is my button disabled code inside (index.html):**

```
ng-disabled="epUpdateAllForm.$invalid || epUpdateAllForm.$pending"
```

**In controller :**

```
    if((($scope.epUpdateAllForm.$invalid)  || ($scope.epUpdateAllForm.$pending)) == true) {

        console.log("Some mandatory fields is not completed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check button is disabled using `angular.element(..).prop()`

```
var target = angular.element(document.getElementById("#buttonIdHere"));
if (target.prop('disabled')) {
    // Button is disabled
}
```

**Option 2**
Watch for `yourForm.$valid`, `yourForm.$invalid` & `yourForm.$pending` in your controller

```
var isFormValid = false;
$scope.$watch('yourForm.$valid', function(newVal) {
    isFormValid = true;
});

$scope.$watch('yourForm.$invalid', function(newVal) {
    isFormValid = false;
});

$scope.$watch('yourForm.$pending', function(newVal) {
    isFormValid = false;
});
```

And simply check if `isFromValid` is true before executing your submission logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the logic of `submit`, then you can pass a form object to the handler `submit`.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2e656un/1/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function(form) {
      if (form.$invalid)
        console.warn('Form is invalid');
      else
        console.log('Form is valid');
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <form name="testForm">
      <label> This field is required
        <input type="text" name="testInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
      </label>
      <button ng-click="submit(testForm)">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```